# map function on an array throwing undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

While trying call map function on an array throwing undefined error. Can someone please help me to resolve the issue. I have attached the sample react code where its getting failed.
[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<div className="main-side-bar">
  <ul>
    {SideBarItems.length != 0 &&
      SideBarItems.filter((data) => data.linkName == moduleName).map((data) => {
        return (
          <>
            <li>
              <h4 className="side-bar-section-header">{data.pageName}</h4>
            </li>
            {data.sideBarLinkNames.map((items) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <li>
                    <h5>{items.sectionName}</h5>
                    <ul className="side-bar-section-header-links">
                      {items.sectionLinks.map((sectionLinks) => {
                        return (
                          <>
                            <li>
                              <Link
                                onClick={() =>
                                  clikedSideBarLink(
                                    sectionLinks.resourceId,
                                    items.sectionName
                                  )
                                }
                                href="#"
                              >
                                {sectionLinks.linkName}
                              </Link>
                            </li>
                          </>
                        );
                      })}
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      })}
  </ul>
</div>;
```

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: @FireFighter I have attached the code

Comment: What is the error? What is `undefined`?

Comment: Its failing at below line with undefined error.                                                                                                                             <h4 className="side-bar-section-header">{data.pageName}</h4>

Comment: Then every data object probably doesn't have the `sideBarLinkNames` attribute. Have u tied logging `sideBarLinkNames` for every data object?

Comment: ***What*** is `undefined`? Your code is trying to access `.map` on something that's `undefined`. There are three different lines with `.map` in them. One of them is failing. You show the line number *but we don't know what it corresponds to*.

Comment: @VLAZ added line number screenshot for reference.

Comment: Looks like SideBarItems.filter(data => data.linkName == moduleName) is not returning any record. What is the value of moduleName?

Comment: @Ayaz it returns an empty array, if nothing was found. The problem is not there

Comment: @FireFighter You are right its throwing error for sideBarLinkNames. But I'm not sure why it is throwing as the sideBarLinkNames is present and I'm trying to access the same only.

Answer (score 0):

The way I organized my data in firebase was wrong. I'm new the javascript and its a new learning for me.
Thanks to all who spent time in helping.

@FireFighter Thanks for pointing the mistake. I spent some time to investigating the issue by debugging and finally found the mistake. Below is the new format of data for the field `sideBarLinkNames`.

[image]

[image]